# Jenkins Ant and dynamic build.properties files

Tags: ant, jenkins

I have a single code based being used to build an application for multiple platforms.

Locally I have setup a main build-env.properties file, and a series of additional *.properties files that I use to switch settings for the different platforms I am publishing to.

Doing my build on the command line I simply use the command:

```
ant build -propertyfile dev-build.properties
```

How can I do this in Jenkins?

I currently use the "Invoke Ant" Build Step with the target set to build, but am at a loss for how to specify the secondary propertyfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not exactly the same, you can take the contents of those properties and put them into the Jenkins Invoke Ant build step, utilizing the properties advanced field.

**The most basic way:**

- You will need to create a new task for each different set of sub properties you wish to utilize.
- In your "Invoke Ant" build step, if you press <kbd>Advanced...</kbd>, this reveals a "Properties" field, you can copy the properties from one of your *.properties files into that field.
- Repeat for each different properties file you wish to utilize.

Comment: I thought of this later, which is the way we have been doing it for other projects, but I was really looking for a way to use the build properties files that we setup.

Answer (score 2):

[Parametrized build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) might help you. This is assuming the number of properties you are changing is one or two. So when you run a job, you get a drop-down to select you OS and go.

Though, as I have mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985358/how-to-configure-jenkins-in-order-to-build-project-using-ant-and-custom-args/12002799#12002799) , what goes against this plugin is that it makes the process manual

---

On this thread [Hudson / Jenkins: share parameters between several jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427871/hudson-jenkins-share-parameters-between-several-jobs/12454622#12454622)  you can read the 2nd option in Anders's answer as an alternate approach.

Comment: We do have the Parameterized build plugin available, so I will take a look and see if we can make that work for us.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach for this is using a parameterised job with file parameter(refer to [doc](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) for creating the builds). Mentioning the file location as "**propertyfile**" would help. This would be better than reconfiguring the job again and again to run a build (To copy the properties file to the input location).